# How to make proxy http to tcp to send only raw "body" using envoy?

Tags: http, tcp, lua, envoyproxy

I want to send http request to envoy and after that envoy send only `body` to tcp server

My steps:

- Create tcp listen port `nc -l 13370`
- deploy envoy in docker on same host (`:10000` port)
- Execute command `curl -d "Hello" -X POST localhost:10000`
  I use this envoy settings

```
static_resources:

  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 10000
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
                http_filters:
                  - name: lua_filter_cutting_head
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
                      default_source_code:
                        inline_string:
                          function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                            request_handle:headers():remove("host")
                            request_handle:headers():remove("user-agent")
                            request_handle:headers():remove("x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms")
                          end
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: cluster_0

  clusters:
    - name: cluster_0
      type: STATIC
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 192.168.0.23
                      port_value: 13370
```

Client --(http)-- envoy --(tcp)-- tcp_server (receive only "Hello)

So i want to see on my tcp_server only "Hello", but i see

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
accept: */*
content-length: 5
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
x-forwarded-proto: http
x-request-id: 8cc7670c-faf5-4ca8-aa97-b3674d81c28a
x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms: 15000

Hello
```

Comment: Maybe change ```content-type``` to ```text/plain```? - Like: ```data:text/plain,Hello```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working config

````
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 127.0.0.1
      port_value: 9902
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 10000
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                            headers:
                              - name: ":method"
                                string_match:
                                  exact: "POST"
                          route:
                            cluster: service
                            upgrade_configs:
                              - upgrade_type: CONNECT
                                connect_config:
                                  allow_post: true
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                http2_protocol_options:
                  allow_connect: true
  clusters:
    - name: service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 192.168.0.31
                      port_value: 13370
    ```
````